# What is needed to make a Philosopher's Stone?

Tags: objects

It is said that four elements are needed to make a Philosopher's Stone. These are derived from the first matter associated with Chaos. I also heard once that the water of life was needed, which, back then, meant alcohol.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [the Opus Magnum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnum_opus_(alchemy)).

The Wikipedia article lists four *stages* for the production:

> - *nigredo*, a blackening or melanosis
> - *albedo*, a whitening or leucosis
> - *citrinitas*, a yellowing or xanthosis
> - *rubedo*, a reddening, purpling, or iosis

What the processes contain is however debated, with various alchemists of the period disagreeing with one another.